# Playing a specific video file when there are multiple buttons, videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, each

## Problem

I have four divs each with their own video file and button.

- Right now, it is coded in a way that it only works with one file, but unfortunately not all of them.
- I've tried using `.each` and using the index of the element, but I kept running into an issue where `.pause() was not a function`

### Codepen

https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/NBvPjx

### Objective

- Clicking on a group's button should play that group's specific video file

### scripts.js

```
    $(function(){

   function playVideo() {

            var video = $(".video--inline")[0];

            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                video.muted = false;
            } else {
                video.pause();
                video.muted = true;
            }

            // Loads the clip again, so that it reverts back to the poster image
            video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
                video.load();

                $("button").find("i").removeClass("fa-pause");
                $("button").find("i").addClass("fa-play");
            });
        }

        $("button").click(function(){
            playVideo();
        });
    });
```

### index.html

```
<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-1.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-2.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-3.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-5.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `click` event to your `playVideo` function then target video like this:
`var video = $(e.target).closest('.group').find('video')[0];`

```js
    $(function(){

   function playVideo(e) {

            var video = $(e.target).closest('.group').find('video')[0];

            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                video.muted = false;
            } else {
                video.pause();
                video.muted = true;
            }

            // Loads the clip again, so that it reverts back to the poster image
            video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
                video.load();

                $("button").find("i").removeClass("fa-pause");
                $("button").find("i").addClass("fa-play");
            });
        }

        $("button").click(playVideo);
    });
```

```css
.group {display:inline-block; width:20vw}
video {width:20vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-1.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-2.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-3.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <video src="https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/10/nsa-decoded/html/asset/video/p1/p1-5.webm" class="video--inline"></video>

  <div class="button__wrapper">
    <button>Listen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
We're passing a function name as a parameter to the click handler:
`$("button").click(playVideo)`
So `playVideo` will be called on click and the click `Event` object will be passed to `playVideo` as a parameter (we called it `e`): `function playVideo(e)`.
`e.target` is the clicked element (button).

Then we're traversing from the button to the corresponding `video`.

Comment: It looks like it works as intended. Do you mind describing passing `e` to the `playvideo` function and your thought process behind using `e.target` in this case. I'm also curious about how passing `playVideo` to the button click works in this case and how this is different from a click function?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen, thank you, I've updated my answer. English is not my native language, sorry if something is still unclear. Will be happy to clarify.